# How to save a time from the time picker and compare it

Tags: android, time, compare, timepicker

I'm writing an app where I need to get the user set time from the start time time picker, and a user set time from an end time time picker. Then compare the start time and the end time with the current time. If the current time equals the start time the silence the phone. If the end time equals the current time un-silence the phone. Any help, especially code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

```
public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener sTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            sHour = hourOfDay;
            sMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
            displayToast();

        }
    };

    public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener eTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            eHour = hourOfDay;
            eMinute = minute;
            updateDisplayE();
            displayToastE();

        }
    };

    public void updateDisplay() {
        startTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(sHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(sMinute)));
        final int compareStartHour = sHour;
        Log.e("beginning", "Value " + sHour);
    }

    public void updateDisplayE()
 {
        endTime.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(eHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(eMinute)));
    }

    private void displayToast() {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(
                        startTime.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void displayToastE() {
        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(
                        endTime.getText()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private static String pad(int c) {
        if (c >= 10)
            return String.valueOf(c);
        else
            return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preset_edit);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        TextView eventTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewEvent);
        startTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
        endTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEndTime);

        startTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        endTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Calendar` class instance:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, tPicker.getCurrentHour());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, tPicker.getCurrentMinute());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, tPicker.getCurrentSecond());
//you can also set the day, month, year etc., default values are today's
```

and then call

```
calendar.getTimeInMillis()
```

which will return you the time value in milliseconds (`long`), which you can easily compare to another.

For details, refer to the [`Calendar`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Get time from TimePicker and save it:

```
Time selectedTime = new Time(sHour, sMinute, 0);
```

Compare it with current time or any other time:

```
Date time = MyClassName.convertStringToTime(selectedTime.toString());
```

And pass both date values to a function:

```
public static int compareTime(Date date1, Date date2) {
        int result = date1.compareTo(date2);

        if (result > 0) //
        {
            return 1;
        } else if (result == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;

    }
```

Edit:
public static class MyClassName{
    public static Date convertStringToTime(String strTime)
            {
                System.out.println("Time to be converted:"+strTime+".");
                Date dateTobeReturned = null;

```
            DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DateUtility.TIME_FORMAT);

            try {
                dateTobeReturned = sdf.parse(strTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Time: " + sdf.format(dateTobeReturned));


            return dateTobeReturned;
        }
    }
```

Please ask if you have any doubt. Hope it helps.

Comment: with the tPicker.getCurrentHour() exactly what would you be referring to with tPicker? This is my method for my time pickers. public TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener sTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
   sHour = hourOfDay;
   sMinute = minute;
   updateDisplay();
   displayToast();
     }
 };

Comment: Its TimePicker variable @user2247767

Comment: okay, it's wanting me to match the constructor time which carries no parameters so I'm unable to get the hours and minutes @TheReader

Comment: @user2247767 Can you show some of your code in your question? Please edit it. So I can get some idea about that exactly

Comment: I have added some code. I have two buttons, in which you click and they bring up the time picker. One for start time the other for end time.

Comment: Ok, I see.. You are using TimePickerDialog and I had used TimePicker. Both have different constructors and methods. Wait. I will edit my answer and let you know @user2247767

Comment: Yea same deal, still wants me to have that time constructor empty. @TheReader

Comment: You have imported import android.text.format.Time; .. Change to import java.sql.Time; @user2247767

Comment: What about DateUtility? It asks me to change to DateUtils but then errors out the convertStringToTime method. @TheReader

Comment: "The method convertStringToTime(String) is undefined for the type DateUtils" this is the error it gives me @AReader

Comment: @user2247767 DateUtility was a custom class in my project in which I had kept function  convertStringToTime(String) . So you will have to change the class name in which your method  convertStringToTime(String)  is kept.

Comment: it force closed my app unfortunately @AReader

Comment: @user2247767 Can you post the logcat o/p in pastie.org and show me?

Comment: Where is logcat? @user2247767

Comment: I put the logcat on there. Its a null pointer exception. @AReader

Comment: Please give me the link of logcat paste. @user2247767

Comment: Ok. Can you paste your latest code and give me a link? @user2247767

Comment: @user2247767 Did you debug the code? Something is null near line 130 of your activity.

Comment: I'm not very skilled at this android programming. So honestly I can debug all day and still don't know what's wrong. I appreciate all your help though @AReader

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this..It works for me...First take a time from TimePickerDialog and get it into String then apply following code..

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
            java.util.Date d_min = null;
            java.util.Date d_max = null;
            try {
                d_min = sdf.parse(time_min);//time_min is the Minimum time in String
                d_max = sdf.parse(time_max);time_max is the Maximun time in String
                d_compare = d_max.compareTo(d_min);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 if (d_compare < 0) {
                check = 3;
                showDialog(0);
            }
```

You can compare current time like this..Hope this will help you..
You can also take a look at this...[current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611059/how-to-get-the-current-time)

And this...[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005749/how-to-get-the-time-on-the-current-android-device)

Comment: I definitely will, I'm going down the list trying all the suggestions, if they work, I will accept. Thanks again! @Meghs

Comment: You said this works for you, so did you constantly get a syntax error right after java.util.Date d_max = null; ? Wanting you to add another {? @Meghs

Comment: No it doesn't give any syntax error.Work fine in my case.If you get an error then try to use Date object.